# Buttons only for admin role

Tags: c#, wpf, button, datagrid

I want to make regular button from wpf form and cell button from datagrid visible only for admin.

Button from DataGrid

```
/DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Connect">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Add room" Name="addRoomButton" Click="addRoomButton_Click"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So im taking user from db, and pass this parameter into main window. Is there any ways to do this correctly?

My WPF windows consturctor:

```
public ChatWindow(string currentUser, bool isAdmin)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Username = currentUser;      
        IsAdmin= isAdmin;

        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:7195/chat")
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();           
    }
```

Comment: It's worth considering to introduce a dedicated data type for the admin role instead of a flag to indicate the actual role. As the admin view gets more and more complex and unique, using a single data type and tons of triggers in order to individualize the views will get very hard to extend and maintain quite soon. It seems reasonable to maintain individual templates for each role instead. Alternatively, use a template selector based on the IsAdmin property. If it's only a button that will ever make the difference, implementing a trigger based on the IsAdmin property seems to be sufficient.

Comment: @BionicCode sounds reasonable, but in my case admin  has few more buttons than regular user, so it’s prorbably not reason for templates. But I clearly understand your opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `IsAdmin` is a public property of the parent window, you could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to it and sets the `Visibility` property of the `Button` accordingly:

```
<Button Content="Add room" Name="addRoomButton" Click="addRoomButton_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAdmin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```